# reason for transaction holding snapshot (postgres, dbeaver)

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

As per my understanding, I can see that a transaction is holding a snapshot by either of the columns `backend_xid` or `backend_xmin` not being `NULL` in `pg_stat_activity`.

I am currently investigating cases where `backend_xid` is not null for sessions from dbeaver and I don't understand why the transaction is requiring a snapshot. This is of interest as long running transaction that are holding a snapshot can cause problems, for autovacuum for instance.

My question is: Can I (serverside) find the reason why a transaction is holding a snapshot? Is there a table where I can see why the transaction is holding a snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backend_xid` is the transaction ID of the session and does not mean that the session has an active snapshot.  [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) says:

> Top-level transaction identifier of this backend, if any.

`backend_xmin` is described as

> The current backend's `xmin` horizon.

“`xmin` horizon” is PostgreSQL jargon and refers to the lowest transaction ID that was active when the snapshot was taken. It is an upper limit of what `VACUUM` is allowed to remove.

Comment: TY Laurenz! My idea that `backend_xid` being not NULL indicates that the transaction is holding a snapshot came from an article from you.See https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/ In section 'Long-running transactions and VACUUM' you use `WHERE backend_xmin IS NOT NULL OR backend_xid IS NOT NULL` and in the comments you say 'If you look at the query I provide, you will see that it checks backend_xmin and backend_xid. You will see that your read-only READ COMMITTED has both values set to NULL between queries' I guess I misunderstood you in the article.

Comment: This article for instance disagrees though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-autovacuum-tuning#long-running-transactions It says backend_xid can hold back autovacuum.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. You were asking about snapshots, but my article and the Microsoft documentation are talking about what holds up the progress of `VACUUM`. An active transaction ID in a session is no snapshot, but it still blocks `VACUUM` progress.